# Where is the source of dropdown list?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to edit an existing excel workbook, I was requested to add to existing dropdown list some options. However, I can't find the source as it only stands "=Lists!$H$1:$H$27", and I don't have a sheet called Lists. Also, it wasn't manually typed.

Comment: Is `Lists` maybe a hidden worksheet?

Comment: Either Lists is a hidden sheet, or it is another excelsheet in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, @squillman was right to suggest that the Lists sheet was hidden.

The sheet has been hidden for some reason and I totally forgot about this function, like literally forgot.

Many thanks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).